# how to get the latest files added to android phone

Tags: java, android

Hi I would like to get the latest files added to the android sdcard using usb file transfer. I am using file.lastModified() to search for new files. But if a folder with bunch of files is transferred from laptop/other means to android phone. The folder and its files, their last modified value did not change in the android phone and hence if i use file.lastModified to filter newly added files, they don't show up. But in some phones, when i do the same process, the lastmodified gets updated for all of them in the phone.

How do I catch the files if the lastmodified is not updated if the file is transferred?

Answer (score 0):

One solution, but costly, could be to store all file paths, size and last modification date. Every time you scan for new files, you compare all files found on the file system to the data stored in the database, and you also update the database.

Comment: While ugly, in a device where the storage can be literally mounted as a USB mass storage device, the mounting computer is perfectly free to muck about with timestamps in any logical or illogical way it chooses, so some variation on this idea would be the only robust solution.  Though looking more carefully at the precise requirement might lead to more efficient possibilities (such as handling only a category of files of interest).

Comment: That will be very costly in terms of both space and computation time as it grows everytime. Fortunately in some phone, if you copy the folder, the android os itself updates the time for all the files. But in some case it just updates the folder and not the files inside the folder.